# Which online chess websites allow you to download their games?

Tags: online-chess, database, websites

I am looking for a list chess websites which allow you to download large numbers of previously played chess games. Currently I have found that lichess [allows you to do so](https://database.lichess.org/).

Are there any other sites?

I do not care whether the game were played by humans or bots, professional or amateurs, time control or anything else.

Answer (score 4):

[Chess-db](https://chess-db.com/public/index.jsp) allows you to search their database for a player and download all their games. For instance, if you search for Magnus Carlsen you get to his [Chess-db profile page](https://chess-db.com/public/pinfo.jsp?id=1503014) where there is a [link](https://chess-db.com/public/download.jsp?id=1503014) which allows you to download all his games in their database. This is very useful for finding and studying the games of famous players or just for finding the games of an opponent so you can try and prepare against them.